# SignalR self hosting on Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, signalr

I'm wrote a small POC application (console application)  on C# (vs2013) that makes: host and clients.

The code of the host side:

```
string url = "http://*:8900/";

using (WebApp.Start(url))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server running at " + url);
    lock (just4lock)
        Monitor.Wait(just4lock);
}
```

**It's working only if I'm run my (console) application with "Run as administrator".**

Ok, now I'm want to move this code to my Windows Service application. When i'm running the same host code on windows service, I'm getting this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.dll

Additional information: The server factory could not be located for the given input: Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
```

My service run as "Local System account". I'm not see any option to make it's "run as administrator".

Do you know a way to make SignalR self-hosting works without administrator?

How I'm can make this windows service run as administrator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried with a registered Startup object instead?

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>(url);
```

then...

```
class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
```

This works just fine for us...

Comment: Hi I have a Web Api for returning data to my client, but also will have a windows service that will process long running tasks. Do I need then to have to SignalR servers? one for my web api and one for my Windows Service? If so, how can I handle that on javascript client? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'd say that's really a brand new question and rather different to that asked above - feel free to ask a new question!

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever Is it really help you? I have same issue and it isn't help me. I created Startup in separate file. Do I need to move this Program?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, and the solution for me was just to add a reference to the assembly `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener` to my project.